# If a question contains two questions, is it OK to leave an answer that only responds to one?

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-answers

Example:

> I'm searching for a good monitor for my PC. I currently own a 21,5"
>   ASUS monitor, which is fine; I'm planning on using the one I currently
>   own as a second monitor and get a new one as my main monitor. I'm
>   willing to pay up to 200 €. I want something that's a little bigger
>   than my current one, maybe 23 - 27" tops. It will be used for gaming
>   and all kinds of office applications as well as graphic design (I'm a
>   heavy user). Because of the latter, it should offer adjustable color
>   modes (or at least some reasonable presets) and be energy-efficient.
>   Full HD resolution (1920x1080), not more and not less. 16/9 aspect
>   ratio is a requirement, I don't want 16/10. Must be available to buy
>   in Germany, no imports. Needs to accept HDMI input, DVI is optional.
>   **Edit:** I don't need internal speakers!
>
> Two questions:
>
> - Which monitors that fit these parameters can you recommend?
> - To everyone who has worked with multiple monitors before: Do you think it is important that both monitors are the same size? Is it
>     confusing if one is bigger than the other one (or bad for the eyes or
>     something like that)?
>
> Feel free to point out if I missed some important parameter. Thanks!

This question contains two questions. If I only have the answer for one of them, shall I still leave an answer? Or would such an answer be deleted?

Answer (score 5):

This meta question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/193412).

The real answer to the problem is: edit the question to focus on one meaningful question, not containing multiple questions. There can be multiple sub questions, but if you can answer *one* subquestion without answering the others then either:

- your answer isn't comprehensive enough
- the question should be split

Answer (score 3):

I'd definitely answer that first question. It's a recommendation and completely on topic here.

That second one is going to be very opinion based. I may or may not mention it in my answer for that reason.

If you are going to answer the question that is a recommendation, then yes, provide an answer. If you are going to answer the opinion question, I'd say no, don't answer it.

---

In either case, the question itself should be edited to remove the non-recommendation question and keep the post completely on topic here. You (generic you) may be conscious of our scope. A new user may not be and may focus on that second question to get a quick upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about your answer [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/359/8) (2k).

If a question asks two (tightly related) questions, then you don't necessarily need to answer both to qualify for an answer. You *do* need to answer the primary question, though.

On Hardware Recommendations, I'm going to say that the *primary question* - unless it's very obviously not - is the one that asks for a recommendation. Hence, in your specific case, the first question asking for a monitor recommendation should have been answered.

That's not to say that other input isn't welcome; your points on the other question were useful, which is why the answer wasn't just deleted. It's been converted to a comment on the question.

Comment: I could see this as akin to some questions that are along the lines of "Valid question here" and then "if relevant please explain how your answer relates to X". I don't see an issue with a question structured as so.

Comment: @Gram the *questions* are fine - but the *answers* to such questions must answer the first valid question, and *only then* the secondary question.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the base of the problem is the question having multiple sub-questions which can cause some confusion when answering.

This being Hardware Recommendations, the main question (if there are sub-questions) is the one asking for a recommendation. This question should always be the one addressed in answers. As for answering other sub-questions, they can be tacked onto the answer, but I personally wouldn't leave them as standalone answers.

So this isn't so much of an answer problem as it is a multi-question problem, which should be revised and split or condensed if possible.